# JSONEditor - onError callback when json is invalid

Tags: angularjs, json, validation

I have implemented a web form which includes json editor based on [JSONEditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor) and [ng-jsoneditor](https://github.com/angular-tools/ng-jsoneditor) libraries. The form will be used as complement for web project which will allow to create/update/delete json data over web interface.

The JSONEditor also takes care of json validation while typing. In my case when json is invalid I also want to disable send button in order to prevent send the form. However this impossible because of limited numbers of APIs, i.e. JSONEditor has option [onError](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md#configuration-options) which is fired only when you try to switch (editor) mode or try to format json.

So, how to handle button disabling in this situation? Perhaps someone from stackovreflow has done it? Any help would be appreciated.